# How to display a div element that is written inside a common component to be visible on one particular page in Angular?

Tags: angular, components, toggle

I have a common filters component written that is used across 2 pages in my dashboard. I want to include a toggle radio button in the filter component that gets rendered only one one of the pages and not both pages. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways. You could get the currently activated route and check if the activated component is a type of the component you are looking for and then disable the toggle button.

**The easier and more conform way would be to just add an @Input() to your component.**

*In the component:*

```
@Input() showToggleButton: boolean;
```

*In the html, that uses the common component, but leaves the toggle button out:*

```
<app-common-component [showToggleButton]="false">  </app-common-component>
```

*In the html of the common component:*

```
<div *ngIf="showToggleButton"> </div>
```